# Mostrar respostas aleatoriamente sem repetir e metodo post

Tags: php, html

Boas, eu tenho a seguinte listagem de respostas retiradas da minha base de dados. E para que a pergunta certa não seja no mesmo sítio, eu fiz um random para mostrar os resultados aleatoriamente. Mas o problema é que ao listar, os resultados também repetem-se, e eu não queria que tal coisa acontece-se.

Agradecia qualquer ajuda para que ao fazer o random, os resultados não se repetissem.

E como posso fazer um post da resposta, visto que as tenho dinamicamente?

```php
$radioname = "pergunta-" . $row['idPergunta'];
$items =[
    $row['RespostaCorrecta'],
    $row['RespostaErrada1'],
    $row['RespostaErrada2'],
    $row['RespostaErrada3'],
];

$rand_items = [
    $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)],
    $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)],
    $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)],
    $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)],
];

echo <<<HTML
    <fieldset name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' >
        <input type='radio' required name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' > {$rand_items[0]}
        <input type='radio' required name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' > {$rand_items[0]}
        <input type='radio' required name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' > {$rand_items[0]}
        <input type='radio' required name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' > {$rand_items[0]}
    </fieldset>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo valor *verdadeiramente aleatório*, por definição, vai se repetir de vez em quando, especialmente se a quantidade de itens envolvidos for pequena.

Para evitar que os itens se repitam em um mesmo questionário, você teria que, à medida em que as perguntas fossem geradas, guardar quais itens foram usados; se o número aleatório se repetir, você teria que sorteá-lo de novo.

Já num escopo mais global, para reduzir a chance de que os valores se repitam, você poderia, por exemplo, guardar estatísticas de quantas vezes cada pergunta foi utilizada e fazer com que as perguntas mais usadas tenham menos chance de aparecer.

Obs: se você tiver uma lista de tamanho fixo, você pode ir simplesmente trocando os pares aleatoriamente, de dois em dois.

Comment: Ja pensei em usar o shuffle, mas não sei como aplicar no meu codigo

Answer (score 0):

o PHP tem a função [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) que altera um array *in-place*, ou seja, altera o array original.

Para usar esta função tu poderia fazer assim:

```php
$items = [
    $row['RespostaCorrecta'],
    $row['RespostaErrada1'],
    $row['RespostaErrada2'],
    $row['RespostaErrada3'],
];
shuffle($items);
```

Visto que tu precisa saber qual é a resposta correta eu aconselho alterar a estrutura do array:

```php
$radioname = "pergunta-" . $row['idPergunta'];
$items = [
    [
        'resposta' => $row['RespostaCorrecta'],
        'correcta' => true,
    ],
    [
        'resposta' => $row['RespostaErrada1'],
        'correcta' => false,
    ],
    [
        'resposta' => $row['RespostaErrada2'],
        'correcta' => false,
    ],
    [
        'resposta' => $row['RespostaErrada3'],
        'correcta' => false,
    ],
];

shuffle($items);

echo "<fieldset name='pergunta-$radioname' id='pergunta-$radioname' >";

foreach ($items as $i => $item):
    $correcta = $item['correcta'] ? "resposta-correcta" : "" ;
    echo <<<HTML
    <label>
        <input type='radio' required name='$radioname' id='$radioname-$i' class='$correcta'> {$item['resposta']}
    </label>
HTML;
endforeach;
```

Porém acho que seria melhor validar se a resposta está certa no servidor, senão qualquer usuário com um pouco de conhecimento poderá descobrir qual é sua resposta correta inspecionando o `radio`.

Comment: isso é php puro ??

Comment: Sim, porquê?
Achou alguma coisa errada no código?

Comment: não é só um pouco diferente do que eu costumo usar, nunca usei por ex " endforeach" e pq esta a dar erro

Comment: eu uso `endforeach` quando tem HTML dentro dele. Senão fica fácil esquecer de onde vem o `{` lá embaixo do código depois.
Pra usar essa sintaxe é so abrir o `foreach` com `:` ao invés de `{`.
O mesmo vale para o `if` e o `for`. [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)